# MySQL select order doesn't order by date

Tags: mysql, timestamp, left-join

Good evening,

wanted to write a MySQL which compares the latest value ('Close') of a group three days ago to the latest value of today for the same group. This was not the problem, it works. But it doesn't sort by date. Every new entry got a timestamp and, as I stated already, I want the latest entry of a day.

```
SELECT p1.ticker, p1.date, p1.close, p1.close - p2.close
FROM prices AS p1
LEFT JOIN prices AS p2 ON p1.ticker = p2.ticker
WHERE DATE( p2.DATE ) = CURDATE( ) -3
AND DATE( p1.DATE ) = CURDATE( ) 
GROUP BY p1.ticker
ORDER BY p1.DATE DESC , p2.Date DESC
```

You see I use Curdate, but I tried Current_Timestamp, too. The result of p1.close - p2.close shows that SQL took the wrong entry. Wrong = not the latest one. If you can help, thank you.

--- Edit --- Example Data

```
CREATE TABLE prices (
  ticker varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Close` decimal(24,4) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Data for table 'prices'
--

INSERT INTO prices (ticker, Date, Close) VALUES
('FB', '2014-04-01 16:24:29', 22.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-01 16:24:38', 23.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 15:09:46', 33.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 15:09:52', 36.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:09:42', 72.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:09:31', 61.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:09:19', 57.2500),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:09:13', 57.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:09:06', 56.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:08:37', 52.2300),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:08:25', 55.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:08:05', 65.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:07:54', 77.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:08:00', 71.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:09:48', 69.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:09:53', 66.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:09:59', 62.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:10:05', 63.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:10:15', 42.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:10:21', 39.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:10:28', 27.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:10:40', 32.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:10:45', 33.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:10:49', 32.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:10:55', 29.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:10:59', 24.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:11:06', 19.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:11:11', 18.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:11:16', 19.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:11:21', 22.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:11:26', 16.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:11:38', 11.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:11:43', 22.0000),
('FB', '2014-04-04 20:11:48', 66.0000),
('TSLA', '2014-04-01 23:10:52', 72.0000),
('TSLA', '2014-04-04 23:11:00', 62.0000);
```

Desired Output should be

```
FB 66.0000 43
TSLA 62.0000 -10
```

Comment: Are your dates stored as dates or strings?

Comment: can you post some sample data?

Comment: Added the data above and the structure of the table.

Comment: Your usage of `group by` is invalid. Every other DBMS would reject your query. MySQL prefers to avoid error message at any costs even if that means it will return "random" data (although MySQL calls it indeterminate though). See here for details: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another self join for the maximum date

```
SELECT p1.ticker, p1.date, p1.close, p2.close c1,p1.close - p2.close
FROM prices AS p1
 JOIN 
(SELECT ticker,MAX(date) date 
 FROM prices 
 WHERE DATE(DATE ) = CURDATE( ) 
 GROUP BY ticker)
pr1 USING(date,ticker)
LEFT JOIN prices AS p2 ON p1.ticker = p2.ticker
WHERE DATE( p2.DATE ) = CURDATE( ) -3
GROUP BY p1.ticker
ORDER BY p1.DATE DESC , p2.Date DESC ;
```

For `FB`  group the difference will be 44 not 43 because from current date - 3 days the minimum close entry is 22 so the latest close entry for today is 66 and - 22 will be 44 not 43

### [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94a87d/17)

For more optimal results to exactly pick the oldest close entry for last three days you can do so

```
SELECT p1.ticker, p1.date, p1.close, p2.close c1,p1.close - p2.close
FROM prices AS p1
 JOIN 
(SELECT ticker,MAX(date) date 
 FROM prices 
 WHERE DATE(DATE ) = CURDATE( ) 
 GROUP BY ticker) pr1 USING(date,ticker)
LEFT JOIN prices AS p2 ON p1.ticker = p2.ticker
JOIN 
(SELECT ticker,MIN(date) date 
 FROM prices 
 WHERE DATE(DATE) = CURDATE() -3
 GROUP BY ticker) pr2 
ON(pr2.date=p2.date AND pr2.ticker=p2.ticker)
ORDER BY p1.DATE DESC , p2.Date DESC ;
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94a87d/26)

Answer (score 1):

your date maybe its a string. try that:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(p1.DATE,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s') DESC,STR_TO_DATE(p2.DATE,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s') DESC
```

Comment: Well, this seems not to be the solution. I use timestamp, date + time. I posted my data and structure above. But thank you echo_me

Comment: its ordering well by date . whats the problem ? can you show your wished result ?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, just took a look on the output. I edited my post and added the desired output in my introducing post. Will take a try on your solution now.

Comment: its the group by function... its an invalid group so the numbers are incorrect.

Comment: do you mean this `ORDER BY p1.DATE ASC` ?

Comment: no the OP does a group by ticker, but thats incorrect. which is why the results look weird

Comment: yeah, come close to the result. Well, M. Khalid gave a good solution. But I will take a look on your solution too, echo_Me, and will remind what you said, John Ruddell. Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 0):

you can do them separately with a limit to get the correct result see [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84a63/9)